# 2007 GMC Sierra Rod Assembly for the Spare Tire

Tags: gmc

We recently purchased a 2007 GMC Sierra and are looking for some details on the assembly for the spare tire. The truck did not come with the rod assembly for the spare tire and we were hoping to make some ourselves, but need some help determining the size of the male adapter at the end of the rod picture below. [image]

We've tried 3/8 extension but it just spins inside the spare tire hoist.

Comment: My guess is a used unit from a salvage/wrecking  yard would be a lot less work

Comment: @mikes they are expensive and hard to find, at least in my area. All the dealers buy them for their used cars, and keep the demand high. The last time I asked for the jack setup for a truck of mine it was $100, I chose to do the same thing as the OP because of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the size you need. It's a hex most of the time, I thought about welding several nuts of the correct size together on the end of tubular steel. That may be the route you need to take.

I had the same problem on a 1999 Yukon so it should be similar to yours

I was able to use a piece of 1/2 inch square tubular steel by itself. It wasn't an exact fit but worked without any modification. I just use a wrench to turn the rod instead of making a t-handle because it was easier to store.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is go down to the dealership and ask to look at the one you need and take your cell phone.
Take pictures of it and take measurement.

Another idea is to ask a person who has the same type of vehicle as you and take
a look at his and ask him if he wouldn't made your taking a pic of it and measuring.